# Can El Niño/La Niña occur again after normal state?

Tags: enso

As I know, El Niño and La Niña usually occurs alternatively, but is it possible that El Niño occurs again after El Niño and return to normal state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the ENSO index record, you can see many instances of El Niño or La Niña occurring multiple times in a row. For instance, the period 1977-1983 and even after that is a succession of El Niño events with normal conditions in between and no La Niña period.
[image: NOAA ENSO index]
Multivariate ENSO Index (MEI) from NOAA